# After modifying the RESX file unable to build my solution

Tags: c#, wpf, resx

When I am trying to modify a string value in my resx file from value a to b and I am trying to build my solution i am getting errors. 
Exceptions: 
Error   1   The namespace 'WorkPermit.Net.Cultures' already contains a definition for 'WorkPermitView'  D:\Naman\Office\Project\TFS- WKP\WorkPermit.NET\WorkPermit.Net\Cultures\WorkPermitView\WorkPermitView.Designer.cs   25  18  WorkPermit.Net

Comment: Let me guess: WorkPermitView.Designer.cs is the file auto-generated from WorkPermitView.resx and you have in addition a file WorkPermitView.cs containing a class WorkPermitView?

Comment: Yes. I understood the problem, Now its resolved, Thanks a lot for your reply.